# MATLAB code conversion to Java

Tags: java, matlab, compiler-construction

I am trying to convert this code into Java Package using the MATLAB compiler and I'm getting this error on building. Can someone suggest anything?

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: An error occurred while shelling out to javac (error code = 1).
Unable to build executable.
```

Is there any specific command line to be included into the matlab function file (for example we include `%#codegen` for C/C++ conversion)

Comment: You say you're using MATLAB Compiler. MATLAB Compiler does not produce Java packages. Do you mean that you're using MATLAB Builder JA for Java?

Comment: yes. but you go into that from MATLAB compiler only right?

Comment: You don't "go into" MATLAB Builder JA "from" MATLAB Compiler. You can access the functionality of both MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB Builder JA from within `deploytool`, if that's what you mean. `deploytool` is not the same as MATLAB Compiler - it is a tool that is made available with either product, and allows you to access the functionality of either.

Comment: Yes sir, that is exactly what i meant. I opened deploytool to use the functionality of both. But i dont think there is any problem with any of those things.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the Java compiler installed. Try executing `java -version` and `javac -version` at a system prompt, and ensure that these both run and give a version that is supported by your version of MATLAB.

Check also that your system environment variables are set appropriately. In particular the `JAVA_HOME` variable should be set to your JDK path.